# What is the recipe for gold mail and other armor and weapons?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

How do you get gold mail?  (I need it to make platinum mail.)

Also I need to know some good armor and weapons recipes. Specifically, recipes for a hammer, sword, and wand. Or torso armor, footwear, and armwear recipes.

Comment: This question is way too general. Different recipes will be "good" at different points in the game, it's mostly dependent on whether you can get the ingredients or not. Go have a look on GameFAQs, there's an equipment guide that shows the stats for all armor/weapons, and an alchemy recipe guide that shows every recipe. Between the two you can figure out recipes you're able to make that are upgrades over your current equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Gold mail = Silver mail + Gold ring + Gold Bracer.

Once you get the Magic armour, you can make:

- Enchanted armour: Magic armour + Enchanted Stone
- Dragon mail: Magic armour + 2 Dragon scale + Raging ruby
- Spiked armour: Magic armour + 2 Magic beast horn + 5 Iron nails

For the rest, try:

- Terra hammer: Terra firmer + 7 Royal soil + Ethereal stone
- Aurora blade: Cautery sword + 3 Brighten rock + Holy water
- Rune staff: Stolos's Staff + Ruby of protection + 5 Magic water
- Macabre mantle: Dark robe + 4 Wing of bat + 3 Terrible tattoo
- Safety shoes: Safer shoes + Ruby of protection + Mythril ore
- Murky mittens: Gloomy gloves + Malicite + 3 Evencloth

Answer (score 0):

I will say that when you get the platinum mail, you don't need the spike mail, as it has lower defence... Plus you can get the platinum mail much earlier in the game, as the furthest place you have to go to is bloomingale...and though you can get a free spike mail when you get the magic key (the armor is in coffinwell behind the purple door in the mayor's house) I already owned 4 platinum mails by the time I got it!